# How to rewrite JText to get my custom text translations from Database and not from files

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, language, jtext

I managed to rewrite system plugin "Language Manager", so now it saves texts for different languages to Database (DB).

Now I do not know how to rewrite JText (that is present across all the application code) so it takes text for each languages directly from the DB and not from the local files. 
The same thing I need to do for "Language Manager" to take data from DB only.

I would appreciate your help! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overwriting or modifying the JText class why not just write a function call function in your model that retrieves your translation from the database and return the string?

Echo the string in your view after including your model:

```
//INCLUDE AT THE TOP OF THE LAYOUT FILE
$mymodel= JModelLegacy::getInstance('ViewName','MyComponentNameModel');

//ECHO OUT TRANSLATION WHERE YOU NEED IT
echo $mymodel->getTranslation('MY_TRANSLATION_STRING');
```

Put this in your model file:

```
public function getTranslation($string)
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $sql = "SELECT text FROM #__mycom_translations WHERE translation = '$string'";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $row = $db->getObject();
    return $row->text;
}
```

Comment: I thought to do so but there is also a built-in language manager interface in backoffice (admin area) that should retreive the text from DB and not from files. (It already saves to DB but not yeat read from it)

Comment: That is not how the language override feature works. The values are not store in the database. The language table in the database only stores a record of what langs are currently installed for your Joomla installation. When you add a language override all it does it write your constant and value to the language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini file in the root of your web folder.

Comment: Unless you are using some custom component that is handling language for you that is. The method I posted above should be the most efficient way to handle custom language strings stored in the database.

Comment: Thank you Terry Carter, This is only solves one part of problem: the UI output . But as I use multiples instances on AWS I can not save and output this into files.

Comment: Using my method there's no need for files, only a database table

Comment: I would like to take this as answer because finally I made almost like you proposed but in more readable way (I will put my way later here). But there is another question on how to output texts  in backoffice(admin) from DB and not files. I mean what hook to use.

Comment: Same process, add a function call to your model in the backend that queries the translations table. Then just echo the returned translation string. Exactly the same as on the front end.

Comment: I know the theoretical general process. I need a specific hook

Comment: I don't quite know what you are referring to, you have to write your own hook (I am assuming the function call). Just add the same function I posted above to the model for your view in your component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42886/discussion-between-terry-carter-and-alex-ros).

Answer (score 1):

I can´t give you a complete answer but maybe a couples of clues to help you solve it.

JText class is located here:

libraries\joomla\language\text.php

Maybe you can override the JText Class with your own and use DB instead of files in your version.

And load it before the core one so It won't be loaded at all.

see here:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1858258&seqNum=8